# Running an EMR job on dynamoDB data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I'd like to run a MapReduce job on a DynamoDB Table.
My question is:

Is it ok to dump all the table (even if it's very big, with tens of millions of entries) into one file on S3?

That is, will the MapReduce know to take "chunks" of these file and distribute to the mappers? Or is the atomic unit provided to a mapper a file on S3, and then I need to break the table into lots of little files, for example make files of at most 10,0000 rows.

If that is the case, if there a way to use the AWS Data Pipline to dump a dynamoDB table into several different files on S3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can see this to export DynamoDB data to S3

https://aws.amazon.com/articles/Elastic-MapReduce/28549

Check Exporting data stored in DynamoDB to Amazon S3.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/EMRforDynamoDB.html

Video at
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlKndm22bXw

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, This helps. But I my question was about running streaming jobs by dumping DynamoDB data to S3 first, and if it was ok to dump it to one "big" file or if I should partition it into several.
Can I run streaming jobs directly on DynamoDB? Your links only talk about Hive queries.